# bazel remote worker deployable jar not working

Tags: java, build, bazel

I have an issue packing [bazel-remote-worker](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/tree/master/src/tools/remote_worker) into deployable jar.

I ran the following command:

`bazel build //src/tools/remote_worker:remote_worker_deploy.jar`

But when I try to run the jar I get this error:

```
➜  bazel git:(master) ✗ java -jar remote_worker_deploy.jar --work_path=/tmp/test --listen_port=3030
*** Initializing in-memory cache server.
*** Not using remote cache. This should be used for testing only!
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no unix in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1867)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
    at com.google.devtools.build.lib.UnixJniLoader.loadJni(UnixJniLoader.java:28)
    at com.google.devtools.build.lib.unix.NativePosixFiles.<clinit>(NativePosixFiles.java:136)
    at com.google.devtools.build.lib.unix.UnixFileSystem.createDirectory(UnixFileSystem.java:309)
    at com.google.devtools.build.lib.vfs.Path.createDirectory(Path.java:829)
    at com.google.devtools.build.lib.vfs.FileSystemUtils.createDirectoryAndParentsWithCache(FileSystemUtils.java:692)
    at com.google.devtools.build.lib.vfs.FileSystemUtils.createDirectoryAndParents(FileSystemUtils.java:652)
    at com.google.devtools.build.remote.RemoteWorker.<init>(RemoteWorker.java:114)
    at com.google.devtools.build.remote.RemoteWorker.main(RemoteWorker.java:621)
```

The only way I can start it is by running the executable from `bazel-bin`:

`bazel-bin/src/tools/remote_worker/remote_worker --work_path=/tmp/test --listen_port=3030`

I'm running bazel latest (currently `a3e26835890a543ff84cce90c879f9196ae06348`) on mac osx sierra.

I tried it with either `oracle-jdk-1.8.131` or `openjdk-1.8.91` and it behaved the same.

End goal is to create a docker image that runs this jar but even inside the `openjdk:8` this jar acts the same...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the question was asked, the paths in Bazel source tree have changed. Nowadays the build commands to get the _deploy.jar are as follows.

```sh
bazel build src/tools/remote:worker_deploy.jar
mkdir -p /tmp/cas /tmp/cache /tmp/work
java -jar bazel-bin/src/tools/remote/worker_deploy.jar \
  --cas_path /tmp/cas --disk_cache /tmp/cache --work_path /tmp/work
bazel build --spawn_strategy=remote \
  --remote_cache=grpc://${IP}:8080 --remote_executor=grpc://${IP}:8080
```

Answer (score 2):

Apparently we're not packing the native code into the deploy jar. I'd actually prefer to refactor the RemoteWorker to avoid most of Bazel's internal libraries, although it's unlikely to happen soon. You could ship the libunix.so with the deploy jar and set the java.library.path appropriately. Alternatively, you can take the entire runfiles tree after building the remote worker (bazel-bin/src/tools/remote_worker/remote_worker.runfiles/).